# passing an argument outside of registers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to pass a second argument to my ls command, `ls -a -l`, but without using a register.

Here, the address of -a argument is at esi. 
I want to place -l somewhere in memory, but not a register.
I've tried with the stack, but `lea esp, [esp-18]` does not place the address on the stack. Instead it places the value (0x00006c2d, for -l).

```
push 0x0000612d ; -a 
mov esi, esp
mov dword [esp-30], 0x00006c2d ; -l
push eax
push edi ; 0000
;sub esp,4
;lea esp, [esp-18] ;  the value is loaded instead of the address
push eax
push esi ; location to -a (2nd arg of argv)
push ebx ; location of /bin/ls (1st arg of argv)
mov ecx, esp
```

I'm wondering how can I add an argument when I'm out of registers.

Comment: First of all, don't access under the stack pointer. Second, `lea` does not access memory so it can't possibly put the value into `esp`. Third, you most definitely do not want to use `esp` as destination for that `lea`. Pick some other register that you can then `push`.

Comment: I know it works with another register.  But how can I add an argument when I'm out of registers ?

Comment: You are not out of registers. But if you were, you could of course put the arguments on the stack one by one reusing a register.

Comment: But what I push to the stack, is the value of the argument, not the memory address.    If I reuse esi, how can it reference 2 memory address. In my example, I push esi for the argument -a

Comment: The `execve` system call takes a NULL-terminated array of pointers to strings as a single argument, and that array has to be in memory.  You only need 2 registers to hold argv and envp pointer args, and a third for the path.  And you don't need to set those up until after you've already written everything to the stack, so you can use `lea ecx, [esp+whatever]`.  (Knowing what sequences of pushes and other insns you used, you know where everything is relative to ESP).  It's not like the `execlp` library function call that takes `...` varargs for argv.

Comment: Can you show the solution for my code ?   With 2 arguments for esi ?     esi points to the memory of the first argument.  How can I push a memory location of a 2nd argument ?

Comment: Load a register with address of last argument, push to stack. Load same register with address of preceding argument, push to stack. Continue backwards.

Comment: This is not working. `push 0x0000612d` ; -a `push 0x00006c2d` ; -l `mov esi, esp`.  It must be an array of memory address. But how ?    If esi is the address to the first argument,  how can I use the same register for a second argument ?

Comment: `push 0x0000612d; push 0x00006c2d; lea esi, [esp+4]; push esi; sub esi, 4; push esi;`

Comment: It's not working... I do other push on stack , like push edi, push ebx...  `push 0x0000612d
push 0x00006c2d
lea esi, [esp+4]
push esi
sub esi, 4
push esi
push eax
push edi
push ebx
mov ecx, esp`  ...    `push esi` before `push ebx` but it won't work either !

Comment: You are missing the NULL terminator for the argv array. Not sure what `eax` and `edi` hold, one of those could be it. You need to push that right on top of the last argument address (that is before the first `push esi`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200527/discussion-between-trogne-and-jester).